# How do I add a custom event listener and get all elements that apply it?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want my own event listener. At the moment I have the following code (just a wrapper for the scroll event without functionality yet...):

```
function onScrollStopped(element, callback, timeout = 48) {
  element.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    callback();
  });
}
```

I currently register my 'event' with the following:

```
onScrollStop(element, () => {
  alert("hi");
});
```

But I would like to register it this way:

```
element.addEventListener("scrollstop", () => {
  alert("hi");
});
```

I've started writing an even with the following code:

```
const event = new Event("scrollstop", { bubbles: true});

<element??>.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  <element??>.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Now how would I know what to fill in at the part with `<element??>`. I want to be able to register this event to every dom node not just window, document or body... How would I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If you bound the listener to every node, wouldn't you get hundreds of simultaneous events firing with every pixel of scrolling?

Comment: only for the elements where I called ```addEventListener("scrollstop")```, this may be only a few elements.

Comment: In that case, (if I'm understanding your question correctly) you would just assign a class to all the elements you want to assign the listener to, and select them with `document.querySelectorAll('.className')`. Since that will return a NodeList object, you may have to loop through them and apply the listener to `this` on each loop.

Comment: I just want to be notified when my event listener is applied to en element and then I want to add the eventlistener that calls the callback to this element

Comment: Why not just add both event listeners at the same time?

Comment: yeah but mine does nothing then... I want mine to get called on the element when the element is scrolled, because I want to add more code to my own soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205760/discussion-between-thingevery-and-swift-lynx).